# get active resource by the unique id

Tags: php

I have multiple resources.. some are sockets and other fopen handlers..

```
$handle = fopen('file', 'w');
print_r($handle);
```

Will output

```
Resource id #20
```

You can get the resource ID by doing `intval($handle);`

Is it possible to reverse it.. If you have the ID is it possible to fetch the resource?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? you could try http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-resources.php if you're on PHP7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On PHP7 you could use the code below to fetch a resource given an id:

```
function fetchResourcePHP7($id){
    if(!is_int($id)) return false;
    foreach(get_resources() as $v){
        if(intval($v)==$id) return $v;
    }
    return false;
}
```

On PHP5 you can use this custom recursive function to achieve the same thing

```
function fetchResource5($id,$array=array(),$restart=true){
    static $result=false;
    if($restart) $result=false;
    if(is_resource($result)) return $result;
    if(!is_array($array)) return false;
    if(!is_int($id)) return false;
    $avoid=['_GET'=>0,'_POST'=>0,'_FILES'=>0,'_REQUEST'=>0,'GLOBALS'=>0,'_COOKIE'=>0];
    if(!$array){
        foreach($GLOBALS as $k=>$v){
            if(is_resource($v)&&intval($v)==$id){
                $result=$v; 
            }
            elseif(is_array($v)&&!isset($avoid[$k])){
                fetchResource($id,$v,false);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        foreach($array as $k=>$v){
            if(is_resource($v)&&intval($v)==$id){
                $result=$v; 
            }
            elseif(is_array($v)&&!isset($avoid[$k])){
                fetchResource($id,$v,false);
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;

}
```

It looks into the GLOBALS variable or into a given $array to retrieve the expected resource if exists.

The usage in function is simple:

```
function any($var){
    $onevar='';
    $anothervar='';
     //an useless example of fetch row here,you could provide $GLOBALS array instead of local variables 
    $someresource=fopen('sometext.txt','r');
    $getresource=fecthResource5(5,get_defined_vars());//always ignore the third argument ,the id 5 is just an example
    return true;
}
```

in the global context the usage is even more simple:

```
 var_dump(fetchResource5(36));//if a resource with id 36 exists it will dump it
```